# TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined using spyOn

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-test, spyon

I am expecting an array to be undefined in a test of my `Angular` app. In order to do that, my test needs to first call a function of my tested component. Within that function, it subscribes to a service's function.

Here is my test class. Including the necessary set up of the service and mock service and the test itself. The test includes commented out lines of what I have already tried.

```
let service: Service;
const mockService = new MockService();
mockService.getById = of([]);

beforeEach(async(() => {
    return TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [leaving out for now],
      imports: [leaving out for now],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: Service,
          useValue: mockService 
        }
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Service);

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

describe('describe test', function () {
    it('test', function () {
      //spyOn(mockService, 'getItemsById');
      //spyOn(mockService, 'getItemsById').and.returnValue(of('nothing'));
      //spyOn(service, 'getItemsById');
      //spyOn(mockService, 'getItemsById').and.callThrough();
      //spyOn(service, 'getItemsById').and.callThrough();
      //spyOn(service, 'getItemsById').and.returnValue(of('nothing')); syntax error
      //spyOn(service, 'getItemsById').and.returnValue({ subscribe: () => {} }); syntax error
      //spyOn(mockService, 'getItemsById').and.returnValue({ subscribe: () => {} }); syntax error
      component.getList();

      expect(component.array).toBeUndefined();
    });
  });
```

All of what I attempted still results in the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

and it references the line in my component's function where I subscribe to the service's `getItemsById` function

my mock service:

```
getById: Observable<any>;

constructor() {}

getItemsById(id: number){
    return this.getById;
  }
```

my tested component that subscribes to the original service's function:

```
getList(): Model[]{
    let temp: Model[] = [];
    for (let item of this.items){
      let id = item.id;
      this.service.getItemsById(id).subscribe(
        singleIdItem => {
          temp= temp.concat(singleIdItem);
        }
      );
    }
    return temp;
  }
```

I did not include my original service since it is being mocked, please let me know if that is needed. I'm assuming the solution is some form of `spyOn` but I have tried everything I have been able to find.

Using Angular 8

Comment: Could you please try and recreate the issue in a stackblitz or codepen or anything similar?

Answer (score 1):

Try this right before the first `beforeEach`:

```
let service: Service;
const mockService = new MockService();
mockService.getById = of([]);
```

I am thinking adding `mockService.getById = of([]);` in the second `beforeEach` (remove it from here now that it is added at the top) is too late (the service without `getById` has already been injected in the providers of the `configureTestingModule`).

=======================Edit===================

I would use `createSpyObj` like so:

```
let mockService: any;

beforeEach(async(() => {
      // can name service (first argument) to anything you want, but I called in service in this scenario. It is internal for you
    mockService = jasmine.createSpyObj('service', ['getItemsById']);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [leaving out for now],
      imports: [leaving out for now],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: Service,
          useValue: mockService 
        }
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

it('should do something', () => {
   mockService.getItemsById.and.returnValue(of([]));
   component.getList();
   // the rest of your assertions.
});
```

Comment: unfortunately this did not work. It results in the same error. I edited my question to include this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In my test, I needed to return the proper value from my service

```
describe('describe test', function () {
    it('test', function () {
      spyOn(service, 'getItemsById').and.returnValue(of([{name: 'name', id: 10, otherId: 12, startTime: 'time', endTime: 'time', description: 'desc', insertTime: 'time', insertUser:'user', updateTime: 'time', updateUser: 'user'}]));

      component.getList();

      expect(component.array.size).toEqual(1);
    });
  });
```

The value returned is of type `Model[]` as defined in my `getList` function in my service.